# Write field name and value form structures to a file

Tags: matlab

I am wondering how can I write a full structure in an output file *.txt with all fieldnames and the respectives values. For example

```
allvariables=

names='raw.txt'
date= = '**/**/2013'
User = Mr/Mrs *
timeProcessing = 20
numberIterations = 1000;
```

Should be written in output.txt with all the information displayed before.

This is just an example but my structure has a length of 50 fieldnames, so I would appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: related question: [Print A Matlab Struct to a Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666862/print-a-matlab-struct-to-a-text-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something you can use:

```
 %// Extract field data
fields = fieldnames(allvariables);
values = struct2cell(allvariables);

%// Optional: add enclosing apostrophes around string values
idx = cellfun(@ischar, values); 
values(idx) = cellfun(@(x){['''', x, '''']}, values(idx));

%// Convert numerical values to strings
idx = cellfun(@isnumeric, values); 
values(idx) = cellfun(@num2str, values(idx), 'UniformOutput', false);

%// Convert cell arrays of strings to comma-delimited strings
idx = cellfun(@iscellstr, values);
stringify_cellstr = @(x){['{' sprintf('''%s'', ', x{1:end - 1}) ...
   sprintf('''%s''', x{end}) '}']};
values(idx) = cellfun(stringify_cellstr, values(idx));

%// Convert cell array of numbers to strings
idx = cellfun(@iscell, values);
isnumber = @(x)isnumeric(x) && isscalar(x);
idx_num = cellfun(@(x)all(arrayfun(@(k)isnumber(x{k}),1:numel(x))), values(idx));
idx(idx) = idx_num;
stringify_cellnum = @(x){['{' sprintf('%d, ' x{1:end - 1}) num2str(x{end}) '}']};
values(idx) = cellfun(stringify_cellnum, values(idx));

%// Combine field names and values in the same array
C = {fields{:}; values{:}};

%// Write fields to text file
fid = fopen('output.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, repmat('%s = %s\n', 1, size(C, 2)), C{:});
fclose(fid);
```

This solution is essentially a variant of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15460600/1336150#15461145). Note that it assumes that each field contains a scalar value or a string, but it can be extended to handle other types, of course.

***EDIT:** added handling for fields storing cell arrays of strings and cell arrays of numbers.*

Comment: Can you explain this : cellfun(@(x){['''', x, '''']}, values(idx)), which is the name of @(x) function and where are the inputs?

Comment: @R_user Sure: at this point `idx` contains a logical (boolean) vector with 1's at the positions of the string values. `values(idx)` extracts those strings, producing a cell-array of strings (which is a subset of `values`). `cellfun` iterates over the contents of each cell in this cell array, passing it to the anonymous function defined by `@(x){['''', x, '''']}`. The anonymous function simply concatenates two apostrophes (one at the beginning and one at the end) to the passed string `x`.

Comment: @R_user The reason for four apostrophes (`''''`) is because the outer two tell MATLAB that it's a character, and the inner two indicate that it's an apostrophe ([you have to use an additional apostrophe to escape  it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045197/do-i-need-to-escape-characters-in-this-matlab-string)).

Comment: While printing I have the error: 'Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs'.  The thing is that in some fields I have to cell arrays. Is it the problem?

Comment: @R_user That is exactly the problem. Like I mentioned in my answer, this solution assumes that the fields store only scalars or strings. You need to special handling of cell arrays. For example, you can try converting them to a comma delimited string to make them appear as a regular string field. I've added an example of how to do it.